# Hard link count

Tags: java, windows, filesystems

What is a more efficient way to retrieve the hard link count of a file, that scales with high numbers of files?

I'm writing an application that scans all files on a volume to draw a graph. It is similar to a freeware program inconveniently called [Scanner](http://www.steffengerlach.de/freeware/), which does takes Hard links into account, and scans really fast, faster than I can achieve in Java without even checking hard links.

---

I already tried checking the hard link count in the following (slow) ways:

(Examples are very simplified for readability)

Via the CMD program `STAT` (windows)

```
process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"stat", "--printf=%h", "\"" + filePath + "\""});

in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String inpMsg = in.readLine();
linkCount = Integer.parseInt(inpMsg);
```

and using a JNI call to `GetFileInformationByHandle`:

```
String lpFileName = filePath;
int dwShareMode = Kernel32.FILE_SHARE_READ | Kernel32.FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
Pointer lpSecurityAttributes = null;
int dwCreationDisposition = Kernel32.OPEN_EXISTING;
int dwFlagsAndAttributes = 0;
int hTemplateFile = 0;
hFile = Kernel32.INSTANCE.CreateFile(lpFileName, dwDesiredAccess, dwShareMode, lpSecurityAttributes, dwCreationDisposition, dwFlagsAndAttributes, hTemplateFile);

Memory lpFileInformation = new Memory(56);
Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, lpFileInformation);

linkCount = lpFileInformation.getInt(40);
```

---

To give an idea of why I want a faster method, here is a list of how fast different processes can iterate over all files on my C: drive (170000 files):

- Alt+Enter on C:\: 19000 files per second (9 seconds)
- Scanner (mentioned above): 7800 files per second (22 seconds)
- Java (no Hard links): 1750 files per second (98 seconds)
- Java (with JNI): 40 files per second (1:10 hours (projected))
- Java (with STAT): 8 files per second (5:50 hours (projected))

The fact that Java is slower than Scanner might have to do with the fact that I'm using `File.listFiles()` instead of the new `FileVisitor`, but I won't accept a speed of 40 files/second which is 43 times slower than without hard links.

(I ran these tests after already scanning several times before. The first scan always takes several times longer)

Comment: Hmm, I changed to Java 1.7's `FileVisitor` design in stead of `Files.listFiles()` and scanning now takes 5.5 seconds. The old way now takes 56 seconds instead of 98 (don't know why all numbers are cleanly ~40% lower, maybe a background process stopped) - I still need to overcome some hurdles (lack of method recursion) before I'll know if everything works out.

Comment: It seems only the old way is faster. Alt+Enter still takes 9 seconds :confused:

Comment: What does the keyboard shortcut Alt-Enter execute ?  I have no knowledge of Java, because it does not execute native CPU instructions nor allow for quick native filesystem operations.